# Best way of calling either StartsWith/EndsWith conditionally

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a method similar to the following:

```
StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;

switch(SearchType)
{
case SearchType.Contains:
list = list.Where(a => a.Reference.Contains("test",comparison));
break;

case SearchType.StartsWith:
list = list.Where(a => a.Reference.StartsWith("test",comparison));
break;

case SearchType.EndsWith:
list = list.Where(a => a.Reference.EndsWith("test",comparison));
break;
}
```

As you can probably guess SearchType is a custom enum I have.

Is there an easier way of doing this, possibily using reflection? The multiple switches seem a bit ugly.

Comment: There isn't. Anything with reflection would be a much worse way to do it.

Comment: reflection have a performance impact.

Comment: It seems you're calling string methods on lists and assigning a boolean value to your lists afterwards. Is this an error in the question, or are you trying to filter the lists depending on the comparisons instead?

Comment: Easier than this, using reflection? No. What is wrong with what you have? If you do anything with reflection, you start relying on the enum members having the same names as the list methods, creating fragile code.

Comment: All of them return bool isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry, error on my half. I am indeed filtering the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which part of that is not easy?

I guess you could have a class for each enum instead, inherit from a common SearchType interface and implement a function called ProcessList - not sure what list is to offer a better function.

Something like..

```
interface SearchType
{
   object ProcessList(object list, string text);
}

class Contains : SearchType
{
   object ProcessList(object list, string text)
   {
      list = list.Where(a => a.Reference.Contains(text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
   }
}
```

Need to do a class for each enum type.

Then you would need to set the SearchType variable like this...

```
SearchType searchType = new Contains();//or something else
```

and your switch could then be replaced with this...

```
list = searchType.ProcessList(list, "test");
```

...Not really easier in terms of coding, but you get a more readable code instead of the switch.

Comment: Thanks - I think I foolishly expected reflection to be of great help here. I think I'll stick with the switch. Muse rule btw!

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a delegate to your function:

```
Test(Func<string, StringComparison, bool> tester)
{
    return tester("test", comparison);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should works :

```
StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;

var methods = new Dictionnary<SearchType, Func<string, string, bool>>();

methods.Add(SearchType.Contains, (str, pattern) => str.Contains(pattern, comparison));
methods.Add(SearchType.StartsWith, (str, pattern) => str.StartsWith(pattern, comparison));
methods.Add(SearchType.EndsWith, (str, pattern) => str.EndsWith(pattern, comparison));

var contains = methods[SearchType.Contains](list, "test");
var startswith = methods[SearchType.StartsWith](list, "test");
var endswith = methods[SearchType.EndsWith](list, "test");
```

However, do you really think it is more readable than a standard switch statement ?