# Simplify if if if to reduce the code size and readability

Tags: c#

I need some help to simplify this huge code that contains hundreds of lines, and i don't really know how to do it.
The code looks really messy, and what i need is to return the model with predefined text color.
Is there any simple method ?

I must explain a little bit more: - There is a list of phones with many models, and if any of this models are available, i need to be printed out with the model number and the color. The list is changing every hour/day...that is how it works.
So then i need to fill out my code with all models, then to search for available ones. Also, all models "EndsWith" a specific code(e.g A23X), and i think is faster to search like this.

```
if (text.EndsWith("model-1")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Sony, Smartphone(model-1)", color = () => Sony.Color1 });
if (text.EndsWith("model-2")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Sony, Smartphone(model-2)", color = () => Sony.Color2 });
if (text.EndsWith("model-3")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Sony, Smartphone(model-3)", color = () => Sony.Color3 });
if (text.EndsWith("model-4")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Sony, Smartphone(model-4)", color = () => Sony.Color4 });
if (text.EndsWith("model-5")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Sony, Smartphone(model-5)", color = () => Sony.Color5 });
if (text.EndsWith("model-6")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Sony, Smartphone(model-6)", color = () => Sony.Color6 });
if (text.EndsWith("model-7")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Sony, Smartphone(model-7)", color = () => Sony.Color7 });
if (text.EndsWith("model-8")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Sony, Smartphone(model-8)", color = () => Sony.Color8 });
if (text.EndsWith("model-9")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Sony, Smartphone(model-9)", color = () => Sony.Color9 });

if (text.EndsWith("model-10")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Nokia, Smartphone(model-10)", color = () => Nokia.Color10 });
if (text.EndsWith("model-11")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Nokia, Smartphone(model-11)", color = () => Nokia.Color11 });
if (text.EndsWith("model-12")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Nokia, Smartphone(model-12)", color = () => Nokia.Color12 });
if (text.EndsWith("model-13")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Nokia, Smartphone(model-13)", color = () => Nokia.Color13 });
if (text.EndsWith("model-14")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Nokia, Smartphone(model-14)", color = () => Nokia.Color14 });
if (text.EndsWith("model-15")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Nokia, Smartphone(model-15)", color = () => Nokia.Color15 });
if (text.EndsWith("model-16")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Nokia, Smartphone(model-16)", color = () => Nokia.Color16 });
if (text.EndsWith("model-17")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Nokia, Smartphone(model-17)", color = () => Nokia.Color17 });
if (text.EndsWith("model-18")) model.Add(new Line { text = "Nokia, Smartphone(model-18)", color = () => Nokia.Color18 });
```

Comment: what is `Nokia.Color10` and so on? what `text` contains?

Comment: Use `switch`, seems like a better choice. And why are there no else if ?

Comment: @Rohit How do you switch on an `EndsWith()`? The effective solution is to put all your colors for each model in a `List`, and use a Regex to extract the number from the text, and then use that number as an index to the list. Bottom line, there is information missing to give a complete  answer but it's obvious that changes need be made outside of the posted code as well as in it.

Comment: Why `= () => Sony.Color1` and not `= Sony.Color1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way of calling either StartsWith/EndsWith conditionally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878915/best-way-of-calling-either-startswith-endswith-conditionally)

Comment: btw, you should store the result of EndWith in a bool instead of evaluate it 18 times

Comment: @Thomas Not possible, each one is different.

Comment: @Rotem by taking the substring of the input string with start index as start index of "model"

Comment: is Nokia/Sony an enumerable?

Comment: @DavidG true. But a least the OP should put `else` block

Comment: @Rohit The length of the comparisons are different.

Comment: @Thomas What would be the point of an else block?

Comment: not to evaluate other checks if one matches? string cannot end with all of those at the same time right... ?

Comment: @DavidG I guess he meant `else if` block. Which avoids unnecessary checks when the condition is already satisfied by another if block.

Comment: Oh, so make each subsequent `if` an `else-if`, yes, that would help.

Comment: @DavidG yes that was the idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create such a dictionary to lookup the `Line` instance from the model-name:

```
Dictionary<string, Line> ModelNames = new Dictionary<string, Line>
{
    {"model-1", new Line { text = "Sony, Smartphone(model-1)", color = Sony.Color1 }},
    {"model-2", new Line { text = "Sony, Smartphone(model-2)", color = Sony.Color2 }},
    {"model-3", new Line { text = "Sony, Smartphone(model-3)", color = Sony.Color3 }},
    // ...
    {"model-10", new Line { text = "Nokia, Smartphone(model-10)", color = Nokia.Color10 }},
    {"model-11", new Line { text = "Nokia, Smartphone(model-11)", color = Nokia.Color11 }},
    {"model-12", new Line { text = "Nokia, Smartphone(model-12)", color = Nokia.Color12 }},
    // ...
};
```

Now you could look if there's a known model:

```
Line matchingModelNameLine = ModelNames
    .Where(kv => text.EndsWith(kv.Key, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .Select(kv => kv.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (matchingModelNameLine != null)
{
    model.Add(matchingModelNameLine);
}
```

Comment: similar to my approach, just that you map keywords with ready lines instead of parameters to create them. Both ways are good, depends if its more about flexibility or simplicity :)

Comment: I'm using this method, looks pretty good, and i already tested some of the lists., but i saw that sometimes the same model appears then if i search again , is not present. Isn't better to use StringComparison.Ordinal ? About performance, i don't see any change in cpu loading :). Thank you.

Comment: @valther: i just wanted to show you that case sensitivity could be an issue and how you can compare case insensitive. But you dont have to, of course. However, i dont understand what you mean with "same model appears then if i search again , is not present"

Comment: First search shows for eg that model-XL33 is available, then search again, is not,..and so on. False results randomly.

Comment: Thats not possible. You have to provide a sample that demonstrates this issue. Maybe invisible characters at the end.

Comment: Yes,that was the glitch, inv char. One last question please : Is there any difference in performance between what it was and now, with this code ? Thank you.

Comment: @ValtherMavem: no, there's no great difference, since the Linq query also uses a loop implicitly and the dictionary is enumerated. But that should not be an issue with so few items. Maybe the fact that my dictionary is only created once and also the line instances.

Answer (score 3):

I dunno, maybe try it this way.

```
Regex model = new Regex(@"?<=model-)\d+");
int model;
String description;
object sColor; //Take the proper type here, no object
if (model.IsMatch("") && int.TryParse(model.Match("").Value, out model)) {
    if (model > 0 && model < 10) {
        description = String.Format("Sony, Smartphone(model-{0})", model);
        sColor = Enum.Parse(typeof(Sony), String.Format("Color{0}", model))
    }
    else if (model > 9 && model < 19) {
        description = String.Format("Nokia, Smartphone(model-{0})", model);
        sColor = Enum.Parse(typeof(Nokia), String.Format("Color{0}", model))
    }
    model.Add(new Line { text = description, color = sColor });
}
```

Comment: I'd say its a more sophisticated and cooler way, but very error prone, easy to get into runtime errors creating an enum that doesnt exist, also its not very flexible, if once he decides to pout model 11 for model 10 match its impossible

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do in such cases is a Dictionary of match -> operation. First extract the data that changes for each iteration and make a class for it, ex:

```
class OperationData{
      public string Manufacturer { get; set;}
      public ColorEnum Color { get; set;}    //some way to persist the color, might be enum value, stringified enum name, parent class...
}
```

now map all the suffixes with parameters needed to perform your operations (I assumed a constructor for OperationData):

```
var operationMap = new Dictionary<string, OperationData>();
//now add all the definitions
oprationMap.Add("model-10", new OperationData("Nokia", Nokia.Color10));
//.....
```

and process the data (foreach for simplicity, but LINQ would be my way to go):

```
foreach(var row in operationMap){
     var key = row.Key; 
     var data = row.Value;
     if (text.EndsWith(key)) {
            model.Add(new Line { 
                 text = String.Format("{0}, Smartphone({1})", data.Manufacturer, key), 
                 color = () => data.Color 
            });
            break;
   }
}
```

The biggest benefit of such solution is that if you need to change logic you do it once for all. You can easily modify the way you match your strings or string formatting or even the Line class you create. You could also imagine to reuse it with different data sets as well.

Comment: The question was how to simplify and shorten the code. This solution does it and adds little more by creating this OperationData class. This is the best answer at least to me +1